# Always link to GitHub pull request from command line after git push?

Tags: git, github

When I check out a new local branch and push it, or if I push to a branch after a while, I get something like the following in my output:

```
remote:
remote: Create a pull request for 'my-branch' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/org/repo/pull/new/my-branch
remote:
```

Is there a way to get this to *always* show up?

Comment: Why should you want to create a PR if you push to an existing branch?

Comment: @dan1st The link still resolves to the right PR so it doesn't matter. Although if there's a way to link to an existing PR if one exists that would be preferred.

Comment: The link will always be the same. Why do you want to display it?

Comment: @dan1st To open the right PR after having pushed as easily as possible.

Comment: What about using [hub](https://github.com/github/hub)?

Comment: The command to create the PR would be `hub pull-request -m <message>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the lines indicate, this message is just a message from the remote side (GitHub), and GitHub only sends it when a new branch is pushed, not on subsequent updates.  I, too, sometimes find myself wishing that it would appear on later pushes.

However, you can use `hub` as suggested, or you could create an alias that opens the URL in your system's default browser.  On macOS, that alias would look like the following:

```
[alias]
    pr = "!f() { open "https://github.com/org/$(basename "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)")/pull/new/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"; };f"
```

And you could then run `git pr` to open that link.  On Linux, you'd substitute `open` with `xdg-open`.

Comment: Nice tip, had to modify slightly to end up at the right url for me:
`pr = !open https://github.com/$(echo $(git remote get-url origin) | cut -f2 -d":" | cut -f1 -d".")/pull/new/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)`

Answer (score 2):

I'd just go with a `gh` alias for those using `git` + `github`:

```ini
[alias]
    pr = "!f() { gh pr view --web; };f"
```

it obviously requires pre-existing installation of `gh`:

```bash
brew install gh
gh auth login
```